# Why is the Bookmark button disabled in Apple Books?

Tags: pdf, books

I'm reading a PDF manual downloaded from the internet in Apple Books. The Bookmark icon is disabled. How can I fix this? Can I fix it directly from my iPad?

Comment: is it just that one pdf? does it still work in other books?

Comment: Seems to be only some PDFs. Also for these PDFs, the annotation button is missing.

Comment: Do you think the author has limited editing for those then?

Comment: Yeah. Why it's possible to disable bookmarks in a PDF I'll never understand. Anyway, can I remove the lock on a PDF I've already added to Books?

Comment: Try creating a pdf then seeing what you can and cannot set. It is difficult to respond to changing comments.

Comment: When I try to mark up (with the drawing tools) a PDF with the same symptom I’m prompted to enter the owner’s password before I can continue.